# Configuring remote access with ssh - Flink

Tags: ssh

I'm following the guide to configure a flink cluster: [flink cluster setup](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-0.8/cluster_setup.html)

see "Configuring Remote Access with ssh" section.

When I `scp .ssh/authorized_keys <worker>:~/.ssh/` substituting < worker > with the ip of the other nodes of the cluster. Unfortunately I obtain the following output:

> ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
>
> lost connection

Some knows which could be the problem?

ADDING DETAILS:
I'm using a cluster composed by three nodes with an instance of Apache Flink on them.

The ip of the nodes are private so I can access them using a hostname from inside the cluster.

So the ip I used instead of < worker > it's the hostname I usually use to access the specific node. I believe it would be good for the nodes to communicate each others inside the cluster.

When this problem occurs, the remote machine's auth.log has such lines:

```
Sep 11 23:34:42 giordano-2-2-100-2 sshd[5019]: refused connect from 192.168.11.X
```

Comment: Do you have full access to the other servers? Can you paste output of /var/log/auth.log while this happens?

Comment: The output: Sep 11 23:34:42 giordano-2-2-100-2 sshd[5019]: refused connect from 192.168.11.$.

Comment: When someone's asking for details in the comments, always add it to the question rather than in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have [tcpwrappers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_Wrapper) blocking your connection attempts.

On the remote machines, take a look at `/etc/hosts.allow`.

Try to put `sshd: 192.168.11.0/255.255.255.0` in it (or whatever your subnet mask is).

Please note that this will allow connections from all your local subnet (providing valid credentials or keypair, of course).

If you want to allow only one server (say, 192.168.11.1) you can put the following in `/etc/hosts.allow`:

```
sshd: 192.168.11.1/255.255.255.255
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have no permissions to modify hosts.allow file.
Maybe I can ask to the cluster manager.

Comment: Ok, please come back here and let us know when you can. Remember that closing a question is important for the Community. Also, please note that you are supposed to have full access to all the systems involved in order to fix such type of issues.

Comment: ok. The cluster manager added the addresses to a white list as you suggested and now everything works.  Thank you!

Comment: Glad you fixed it. It would be intresting to know what OS and version are you working on, because many people would have similar issues with the same distribution, so you should edit both the title and the question to include it, so the question will be much more useful for the Community in the future. For instance, "CentOS 6: Configuring remote...."

Comment: Hi @AndreaGiordano could you confirm what Linux distro were you working on?

Comment: the os version is ubuntu 16